# LinearLayout with full width Android

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

Right now my app layout looks like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/orzmwe02a0l4z77/IMG-1.jpg?dl=0).

I want it to look like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cdxxtunc0h43j6n/IMG-2.jpg?dl=0).

How can I achieve this ? I am using LinearLayout as a child of ScrollView.

Comment: make your layout width=wrap content to match parent

Comment: Check the margins, padding for your scrollview and linearlayout and adjust them as per your requirements

Answer (score 0):

Inside the LinearLayout tags add the property, 
layout_width: "match_parent", like this,

```
<LinearLayout>
layout_width: "match_parent"
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple.

Set the `layout_width` attribute of the white box to `match_parent`.